# How to access pair elements nested inside pair in a vector in stl

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector like this :

```
vector < pair < int, pair < int,int > > > v
```

I want to access all the three elements . How can i do that through iterator?
I have declared the iterator as it1 and it2 below :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{

int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    vector<pair<int,pair<int,int> > > v;
    int n,a,b,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
        v.push_back(make_pair(b,make_pair(a,i+1)));
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    vector<pair<int,pair<int,int> > > :: iterator it1=v.begin();
    vector<pair<int,pair<int,int> > > :: iterator it2=v.begin()+1;
    printf("%d ",(it1->first)->second);

        while(it2!=v.end())
        {
            if(it2->first.first>it1.first)
            {
                printf("%d ",it2.first.second);
                it1=it2;

            }
            it2++;
        }

    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: `v[index].second.first` and  `v[index].second.second`? Also consider using tuple (if you are using c++11).

Comment: You're mixing object access operators `.` and `->` all over the place. In some place you use correct operators, in others you don't. You're very inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow the types.

If `it` is an iterator over

```
vector<pair<int, pair<int, int>>>
```

then `*it` is a

```
pair<int, pair<int, int>>
```

so `it->first` (a.k.a. `(*it).first`) is an `int`, and `it->second` is a `pair<int,int>`.

This means that your elements are

```
it->first
it->second.first
it->second.second
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 //  It may help you !!!

 vector < pair < int , pair < int, int > > > v;
 vector < pair < int , pair < int, int > > > ::iterator it;

 for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
 {
     v.push_back(make_pair(i,make_pair(i+5,i+10)));
 }

 for(it= v.begin(); it!= v.end(); it++)
 {
     cout << it->first << " " << it->second.first << " " << it->second.second <<endl;
 }

// first element access  : it->first;
// second element access : it->second.first;
// Third element access  : it->second.second;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an iterator `it` you can do this:

```
std::cout << "first int: " << it->first << " first nested int: " << it->second.first << " second nested int: " << it->second.second;
```